# How to get all email from deleted Gmail Account?

Tags: gmail, account-management

I am trying to recover my gmail account which I have deleted in mistake. Now I am trying to recover that account but can't be able to recover it. I want to know that is there any possibility where I can recover my all the emails rather to re-open my gmail account?

Answer (score 10):

[Gmail support](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61177) states -

> **I want to retrieve my deleted account**
>
> Residual copies of deleted messages and accounts may take up to 60
>   days to be deleted from our active servers and may remain in our
>   backup systems for an additional period of time. If you delete your
>   Gmail address but wish to have it back, we work to help you recover
>   your deleted accounts whenever possible. However, within a few weeks'
>   time, accounts are usually no longer retrievable. **Note that a
>   successful recovery will only recover the username associated with the
>   account.**

That means even if you contact Google support and recovers your Gmail account, you won't get your mails back. Either way, your only hope is to mail Google support and ask for their help. And I hope it hasn't been much long since you deleted the account.